# Check if value from one dataframe exists in other dataframe and return the position in Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I know that if we want to check if one value exists in a dataframe we use isin(). However, I want the position or positions where it is found in the other dataframe.
Like df1['Column1'].isin(df2['Column2']) only returns True if it is contained in df2. But I want the position where it is found in df2.
1 I do not want to loop over the dataframes because I have a very large dataset. Is there any function in pandas or a quick way to do it without having to loop?

Answer (score 1):

Each line in pandas dataframe has its index (0-... as default or changed by you). If you would like to get the position , try to use `.index`:

`df1[df1['Column1'].isin(df2['Column2'])].index`

Updated:

```
df1['df1_index']=pd.DataFrame(df1[df1['col1'].isin(df2['col1'])].index).astype('int')
df1['df2_index']=pd.DataFrame(df2[df2['col1'].isin(df1['col1'])].index).astype('int')
```

[image]

Comment: I get the index of positions in df1 and I want the matched positions in df2.

Comment: Thank for the update. But it's still not working.

Comment: Can you show your datasets you are testing with?

Comment: I wish I could but we cannot share it. The main idea is that I have two datasets and df1 is smaller than df2. I need a code to find the positions  of df1 values in df2. For instance, df1[column1][0]='Stack' and df[column2][13]='Stack', so the code has to return the position 13 of df2

Comment: My code returns the position. Watch the picture. Can you share a piece of data. Can you show df1.index and df2.index

Comment: There is no column 'LocationPostCode' in df1. Dataframe 1 has columns: pcd7,pcd8,pcds,dointr,doterm,usertype,oa11cd,lsoa11cd,msoa11cd,ladcd,lsoa11nm,msoa11nm,ladnm,ladnmw

Answer (score 0):

You might try this:

```
filtered_df = df1[df1['Column1'] == df2['Column2']]
print(filtered_df)
```

Does this work?

Comment: No, it doesn't work because they have different size.